# Does anyone know how to use StartCom SSL without keystore in Java OR use a custom keystore?

Tags: java, resources, certificate, ssl-certificate, keystore

I have found the following post, which I think I may help because I need a way of verifying my website (that my java application connects to) without having to use the java keystore:

http://www.mombu.com/programming/java/t-ssl-for-java-without-keystores-1366416.html

However, I'm quite new to the world of SSL and don't know which files and passwords I need to use, so if anybody can point me in the right direction that would be great. If you didn't guess, I got my SSL certificate from StartSSL, who are ran/owned/something by StartCom Ltd. Here is a post I used for putting  the details into the keystore:

https://forum.startcom.org/viewtopic.php?t=1390

Thanks in Advance!

**Alternitively, is there any way for me to use a custom keystore. i.e I'll do what I need with the default keystore and then copy the keystore into the .JAR so that I can tell my application to use the one in the .JAR instead of the one in the Java install directory, etc...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create and use your own keystore for your app using the [keytool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) utility which comes with the JDK.

Basically, a keystore is a datastore for your keys & certificates, which will be used in your app either to authenticate yourself to another entity or to digitally sign your messages or any other data.

 A distinct keystore called trustore is used to keep the public key certificates of the entities you trust.
You can have these keystores placed in your classpath and specify the path in your app in code like (these are VM params which will affect all apps running in this VM):

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
properties.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", path/to/keystorefile);
properties.put("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", keyStorePassword);
properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", path/to/truststore);
properties.put("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", trustStorePassword);
```

EDIT:

Yes, you can specify the keystore & trustore locations and their passwords in a property file and load the properties file as `myProperties.load(myProperties.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/proertyfile.properties"));` 
and then use it in your code as (exception handling omitted)(this will not affect any other app):

```
KeyStore mykeystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("/path/from/myproperties");
mykeystore.load(is, myKeystorePasswordFromProperties.toCharArray());
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply Zaki. Just a couple of questions: Which file is actually the keystore and truststore? Do you know if I can do this via getResource() (with the files being in my JAR)? And I'm guessing that these properties will only affect my applications, and are not global...?

Comment: Thanks for that edit, it too was useful. Just to confirm, if my properties file was in the root of the JAR, I could put my keystore file (cacerts) in the root of the JAR as well? AND again, which file is actually the keystore and trust store?

Comment: Yes, you can have the keystore files in the root of the JAR. A trustore is a keystore for the certs you trust, so for example, if you are connecting to "https:/www.SomeSite.com" from your app, then you need to have the cert of that server in your trustore so that the ssl connection from your app is successful.

Comment: If the webserver requires client authentication, then your app has to provide your cert to the server and the ssl connection is successful only if the server trusts your cert, ie, the server has your cert configured in its trustore.

Comment: Perhaps I have phrased my question wrong, as I am familiar with what the truststore/keystore is (kind of). However, I am not really sure on the location of the default ones so that I can copy it...

Comment: You can have the keystore & trustore files anywhere in your client app's project directory, theres no standard location for these unlike in webserver environments like Tomcat or Glassfish.

Comment: Could `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\security\cacerts` be the keystore file then? and would `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\jre\lib\security\trusted.libraries` be the truststore file? Or, Actually, do I need to include the file name in the path?

Comment: Well technically, yes you could, but it would have an affect on the entire JVM installation, and also, cacerts is generally a trustore, well technically its just a plain old keystore, but for managability, a trustore is kept distinct, and also your modification to this cacerts would be overridden incase you install a jdk or jre update.

Comment: Its almost always a better idea to use separate keystores specific only to your app.

Comment: Zaki, I think your misunderstanding my question. I intend to just copy my existing keystore with the information already in into the JAR, so I need to know where the file is to copy. But, I've just noticed that you have put "path/to", so does that mean that I don't need to specify the file name?

Comment: You say "I intend to just copy my **existing** keystore with the information already in into the JAR, so I need to know **where the file is** to copy". Im sorry but I dont follow you. Do you need to use the keystore file (which is a keystore for trusted entities) that comes with the jre, namely, "cacerts.jks" in your app ??

Comment: If you need to use the "cacerts.jks" file found in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security\cacerts.jks" or "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\lib\security\cacerts.jks", then you could copy it and use it in your app, the default password is "changeit". Please note that these keystores are generally used to store the public certs of trusted entities.

Comment: Zaki: Yes, I do believe I need to keystore file in my application. You see I need a way of making my Java app trust my domain on every machine without bundling the JRE in an .EXE using launch4j!

Comment: Then, you could copy the existing cacerts.jks into your project dir and import your domain's public certs into this cacerts.jks and then specifiy its location either with jvm params or explicitly in your app code.

Comment: Zaki Thank you for that confirmation. However, when you say 'location' does that include the file name, or just the directory? Also, my cacerts file does not have the `.jks` ending, is this still the right file because it is in the right location!

Comment: You have to specify the complete path, it means "path + filename", for eg, "C://users/Andy/projects/MyApp/mycacerts.jks". The "jks" is the file extension defining the keystore format. You can omit the extension in the file and it would most likely work.

Comment: Zaki thank you for that clarification, you've helped me alot! (Sorry for the slow reply)

Comment: Zaki Sorry to bother you again; I hope you still reply. What exactly do I load the properties file into?